# Rebus Ad in London tube: "your closet dreams"?

Tags: idioms, nouns, image-identification

[image]

Hello,

I’m wondering if anyone can help me to get the meaning of the last sentence in this tube advertisement (attached).

I’ve deciphered the first part:

> Let's face it, **iron**ing just isn’t in your **genes**! So **bag** yourself some much needed free **ti**(**e**)me and fresh **shirts**. We'll make your **laundry** as bright as a **button**, so you can **dress** to impress. Your _____ dreams about [name of ap], just throw in the _____ today!

But for the life of me, I can’t figure out what’s coded in the last sentence. *Closet dreams*? *Wardrobe dreams*, *wide dreams*? I don’t think any of these exist. Does anyone have an idea?

P.S. English is not my native language.

Comment: I'd go with "Your wardrobe dreams of Laundrapp, just throw in the towel today!"  ('Laundrapp' is the thing being advertised.)

Comment: Yup. It's the icon for the Laundrapp app. https://laundrapp.com/dry-cleaning-laundry-app/

Comment: And it's "pocket yourself some free time."

Comment: @Kate, sweetheart, a question is a COMPLETE sentence followed by a question mark.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the last line refers to "your closeted dreams about smartphones" and the need to "throw in the loofah." But why should anyone "frock to impress"—or for that matter be surprised that "pressing isn't in your dungarees"?

Comment: Just to clarify; 'throw in the towel' is an idiom meaning to accept defeat. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/throw-in-the-towel

Comment: "Ironing just isn't your pair of pants"

Comment: That's almost fun and I'm sorry to point out that it has almost nothing to do with English…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about matching pictures with words.

Comment: I agree with “wardrobe”, because it has the double meaning of (1) a closet-like device (but a piece of furniture, not built in to the house) for storing clothes (as pictured), but also (2) the collection of a person’s clothes (as in “Joe has the physique of a lumberjack, and the wardrobe to match”).

Answer (score 4):

Let's face it, *ironing* just isn't in your *jeans* (genes)! So *pocket* yourself some much needed free *ti(e)me* and fresh *shirts*. We'll make your *laundry* as bright as a *button*, so you can *dress* to impress. Your *wardrobe* dreams about *Laundrapp*, just throw in the *towel* today!

Note that *dream* is used as a verb in this instance, not as a noun. i.e. *your wardrobe [dreams] about...* and not *your [wardrobe dreams] about...*

Comment: Perhaps if you add that *dream* is used as a verb in this instance, not as a noun that will help the OP understand better e.g. *your wardrobe [dreams] about...* and not *your [wardrobe dreams] about...*

Comment: @Mari-LouA - After four months and no better answer, and as this question has been bumped, I've just edited your comment in.

Comment: @AndyT Is 'wardrobe dreams' or 'closet dreams' an idiom in BrE? I've never heard it before (AmE).

Comment: @Mitch it is [your wardrobe] (NP) [dreams about the app] (VP) I would call this ill-effective advertising, but I dont ride the tube.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 ??? I read that a bunch of times. Now that it makes grammatical sense, it doesn't feel compelling to me. 'Wardrobe' is pretty rare in the US (only ever heard in the CS Lewis book). I can sorta see the personification _wanting_ the app, you know, to be a prouder, more successful wardrobe, but really, I think the wardrobe doesn't much care at all _what_ you wear. Well, the ad successfully got me thinking about getting a wardrobe, and not whatever it is selling (pants I think).

Comment: @Mitch I take it to mean [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wardrobe) definition 1.1 *A person's entire collection of clothes* and not *A large, tall cupboard or recess in which clothes may be hung or stored*. Since the whole ad is talking about one's clothes, not one's furniture.